# jQuery / JS calling click functions only on certain media breakpoints / orientation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have the following JS / jQuery I have managed to build, but it does not 100% seem to work with testing. Mainly changing orientation. I only want to click events to fire if in iPad portrait and mobile.

Here is what I have:

```
// mobile
var isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width : 40em)");

// tablet
var isTablet = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width : 60em)");
var isTabletPortraitOnly = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width : 60em) and (orientation : portrait)");

/* mobile cart slideout */
var $miniCart = $('#cart_over');
var $cartLink = $('.mini-cart');
var $siteContent = $('.top-header-container, .main-content, footer');

function cartOpen(){

  event.preventDefault();
  if ($miniCart.hasClass("cart-slide-in")) {
    $miniCart.addClass("cart-slide-out");
    $siteContent.addClass("content-slide-in");
  } else if ($miniCart.hasClass("cart-slide-out")) {
    $miniCart.removeClass('cart-slide-out');
    $miniCart.addClass("cart-slide-in");
  } else {
    $miniCart.addClass("cart-slide-in");
  }

  if ($siteContent.hasClass("content-slide-out")) {
    $siteContent.addClass("content-slide-in");
    $siteContent.removeClass("content-slide-out");
  } else if ($siteContent.hasClass("content-slide-in")) {
    $siteContent.addClass("content-slide-out");
    $siteContent.removeClass("content-slide-in");
  } else {
    $siteContent.addClass("content-slide-out");
  }

}

function cartClose(){
  //clode the lateral panel
  if ($miniCart.hasClass("cart-slide-in")) {
    $miniCart.removeClass('cart-slide-in');
    $miniCart.addClass('cart-slide-out');
    $siteContent.removeClass("content-slide-out");
    $siteContent.addClass("content-slide-in");      
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

if(isMobile.matches || isTabletPortraitOnly.matches){
  $cartLink.on('click', function(event){
    cartOpen();
  });
  $('#cart_close').on('click', function(event){
    cartClose(); 
  });
}

//bind to resize
$(window).resize( function() {
  if(isMobile.matches || isTabletPortraitOnly.matches){
    $cartLink.on('click', function(event){
      cartOpen();
    });
    $('#cart_close').on('click', function(event){
      cartClose(); 
    });
  }
});

//check for the orientation event and bind accordingly
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
  if(isMobile.matches || isTabletPortraitOnly.matches){
    $cartLink.on('click', function(event){
      cartOpen();
    });
    $('#cart_close').on('click', function(event){
      cartClose(); 
    });
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: When i change orientation, so portrait i click link and slides cart in (As expected) i change to landscape and click and it slides in but shouldn't.

Comment: Have you tried using the _if-condition_ inside the _click-event_ instead of outside?

Comment: I think i tired but both click events were inside the one function which i wrapped with if statement but let me try your suggestion...

Comment: Ahh i think that seemed to have done the trick lol crazy! thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your condition may vary by the time (as the mobile-rotating), you shouldn't check it only once.

Change your if-conditions for click-event from outside to inside.

Hope it helps.